# private visibility modifier and subpackages

Tags: kotlin

So I recently started experimenting with Kotlin and I stumbled upon this:

> If a top-level declaration is marked private, it is private to the
>   package it’s declared in ([see Visibility Modifiers](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/visibility-modifiers.html)). Since packages
>   really nest in Kotlin, i.e. package foo.bar is considered a member of
>   foo, if something is private in a package, it is visible to all its
>   subpackages.
>
> Note that members of outer packages are not imported by default, i.e.
>   in a file in package foo.bar we can’t access members of foo without
>   importing them.
>   From: [Visibility and Package Nesting](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/packages.html#visibility-and-package-nesting)

So let's consider the following example:

**File1.kt**

```
package foo

private fun bar() = println("This is bar!!!")
```

and **File2.kt**

```
package foo.baz

import foo.bar

fun main(args: Array<String>) = bar()
```

From what I understand function bar() should be visible in package foo.baz and thus be callable from main(). But when I try to compile the above I get the following error message:

**Error: Kotlin: Cannot access 'bar': it is 'private' in 'foo'**

Is this a bug or has the spec of the language been updated and the documentation hasn't? Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have changed the visibility rules recently, so that packages do not nest any more. So this is not a bug in the compiler, but in the docs

Comment: Thanks, but please remember to document such changes.
So how do package/top-level visibility modifiers work now?

Comment: Packages don't nest, i.e. private in one package is not visible in another one.

Comment: Also, `private` will soon be changed to be visible not in a package but in the file it's declared

Comment: What is the reason to change the behaviour?

Comment: Because our experience showed that it's more intuitive and more useful

Comment: Due to this changes, are you planning to introduce something similar to Java's package-private visibility?

Comment: No, packages are not visibility scopes, only namespaces. Modules work a lot better as visibility scopes.

Answer (score 0):

While it might be as Andrey Breslav wrote, that the rules have changed, you can still use your code even with version 0.12.1218 and 0.12.200.

Since the rules have been changed you shouldn't do it, but if you really want to do it, just change your import statement to:
`import foo.*` instead of importing the bar explicitly.

Comment: But why is that allowed? Should import foo. * exclude private members as well? After all I can't explicitly import foo.bar.

Comment: I have no idea, I just discovered it by coincidence while playing with your code. My guess is that they blocked it programmatically, instead of stripping out the feature completely, and it didn't cover the the globbing one.